# Is there a way to partition a table created from a query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

In BigQuery, I can create a permanent table from a query. Is there a way to make such a table date-partitioned? I can query a date-partitioned table, but I can't create a date-partitioned table from a query.

For example, given a date-partitioned table `tbl`:

```
select col from tbl
where _partitiontime between cast('YYYY-MM-DD' as timestamp) and cast('YYYY-MM-DD' as timestamp)
```

results in a non-date-partitioned table.

Answer (score 1):

To create a partitioned table, you must declare the table as partitioned at creation time either via `command-line` or `API`. These are the only options we have as of today. See more about [Creating and Updating Date-Partitioned Tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables)